# Cmake, error when try to include libraries

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda, gpu, cmake-gui

I am trying to build this library https://github.com/stotko/stdgpu, by following the given steps but I got the following  error as in the attached image , could any one give me the suggestion to solve it

```
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:367 (message):
  No CUDA toolset found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:32 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:243 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:35 (enable_language)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/doubleme/Desktop/stdgpu/-Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrNqY.png)

**CmakeOutput.log**

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.18362 - AMD64
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/9/2020 1:25:48 PM.
Project "C:\Users\doubleme\Desktop\stdgpu\-Build\CMakeFiles\3.18.0-rc3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj -> C:\Users\doubleme\Desktop\stdgpu\-Build\CMakeFiles\3.18.0-rc3\CompilerIdCXX\.\CompilerIdCXX.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\CompilerIdCXX.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\doubleme\Desktop\stdgpu\-Build\CMakeFiles\3.18.0-rc3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.11


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/doubleme/Desktop/stdgpu/-Build/CMakeFiles/3.18.0-rc3/CompilerIdCXX/CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/doubleme/Desktop/stdgpu/-Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_97ed9.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

  cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_97ed9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_97ed9.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"

  cmTC_97ed9.vcxproj -> C:\Users\doubleme\Desktop\stdgpu\-Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_97ed9.exe
```

Comment: Please do not use images as the only means to convey the error. Instead post the **complete** error message *as text* in your question post. Also, did you install **all** of the dependencies before trying to build as described in the [Building](https://github.com/stotko/stdgpu#building) section, including the CUDA Toolkit?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice , yes I installed CUDA Toolkit

Comment: "See also "C:/Users/doubleme/Desktop/stdgpu/-Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"." sounds like very good advice -- inspect the log and see what the problem is

Comment: Hi,talonmies, I am unable to identify the problem  from CmakeOutput.log I added the contents in the file CmakeOutput.log, could some body let me know the problem

Comment: check this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980412/how-to-let-cmake-find-cuda) it is CUDA specific, but you should be able to adapt it to your VS setting.