# How to build OpenCv using Cmake on Databricks

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, gpu, databricks

I'm trying to use GPU with OpenCv in Notebook Databricks , my cluster is already configured with GPU , but the GPU is not working . So I tried to build OpenCv using CMake and set the flag WITH_CUDA = ON , but it's now working . Here is the code I used to build OpenCV using Cmake on Databricks .

```
!mkdir content
%cd /content
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
!mkdir /content/build
%cd /content/build
!cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/content/opencv_contrib/modules  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF  -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF  -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_CUDNN=ON -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON /content/opencv
!make -j8 install
```

**This is the output that I got**

```
/content/build
-- Detected processor: x86_64
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: JPEG_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.1.2, BUILD = opencv-4.5.5-dev-libjpeg-turbo
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: TIFF_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: WEBP_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: WEBP_INCLUDE_DIR
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
-- OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.4.0, BUILD = opencv-4.5.5-dev-openjp2-2.4.0
-- OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.4.0")
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- libva: missing va.h header (VA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /content/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
-- at: /content/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:45 (message):
  OpenCV is not able to find/configure CUDA SDK (required by WITH_CUDA).

  CUDA support will be disabled in OpenCV build.

  To eliminate this warning remove WITH_CUDA=ON CMake configuration option.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:730 (include)


-- LAPACK(OpenBLAS): LAPACK_LIBRARIES: /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so
-- LAPACK(OpenBLAS): Support is enabled.
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Module opencv_alphamat disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen
-- freetype2:   NO
-- harfbuzz:    NO
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "")
-- Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings. 
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
-- Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
-- Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
-- Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
CMake Error at modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:37 (message):
  DNN: CUDA backend requires CUDA Toolkit.  Please resolve dependency or
  disable OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF


-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /content/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.rvv.cpp
-- highgui: using builtin backend: NONE
-- rgbd: Eigen support is disabled. Eigen is Required for Posegraph optimization
-- Found 'misc' Python modules from /content/opencv/modules/python/package/extra_modules
-- Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from /content/opencv/modules/core/misc/python/package
-- Found 'gapi' Python modules from /content/opencv/modules/gapi/misc/python/package
-- Found 'misc' Python modules from /content/opencv/modules/python/package/extra_modules
-- Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from /content/opencv/modules/core/misc/python/package
-- Found 'gapi' Python modules from /content/opencv/modules/gapi/misc/python/package
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.5-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               4.5.5-275-ge4abf6e723
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /content/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     4.5.5-51-g7a35d3df
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2022-03-29T16:42:22Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.4.0-1067-azure x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.16.3
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so Iconv::Iconv dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 quirc ippiw ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 alphamat cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java julia matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
--     Applications:                apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI:                           NONE
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   /content/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                /content/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     VA:                          NO
--     Lapack:                      YES (/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so)
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   NO
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /content/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /databricks/python3/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.10)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.10)
--     numpy:                       /databricks/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.20.1)
--     install path:                lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/content/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/content/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Comment: have you tried to install CUDA SDK explicitly?

Comment: @AlexOtt I simply run pip install cuda-python . I was checking about CUDA SDK , but I could not find anything

Comment: Are you able to install the [Cuda toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) on your platform?

Comment: @AndrewH , Here is what I've found in /usr/local : bin/   cuda-11@    cuda-11.3/  games/    lib/  sbin/   src/
cuda@  cuda-11.0/  etc/        include/  man@  share/

Comment: Is nvcc on your path?  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980412/how-to-let-cmake-find-cuda) for some things to try.

Comment: @AndrewH I've added those lines to /root/.bashrc export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin:$PATH" export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" . Then I run !source .bashrc but nothing happend . I still have the same problem . Like the nvcc is not installed at all . The same error as mentioned above keeps popping out